# Getting gawk regex parser to recognise NUL characters

Tags: regex, gawk, nul

I have a series of files which I am trying to process and validate using gawk. A small number of the files a corrupt and contain runs of NUL (0x00) characters which I would like to reject as invalid.

However, it appears that gawk (4.1.1) is essentially ignoring the NUL characters. Here's my minimal code to invoke the issue:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[#/]"   #Split at hash or slash
    OFS = ":"
}

$10 !~ "^[[:digit:]]+$" {
    print NR, $0
}
```

This should print all records for which field 10 is not a positive integer. However, it fails to print a record for which field 10 is '7' followed by a long string of NULs.

How can I get gawk to recognise the NUL characters? I have tried the --posix command line option to no avail.

ADDENDUM: I changed the code to be:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[#/]"   #Split at hash or slash
    OFS = ":"
}

$10 ~ "^7$" {
    print NR, $10
}
```

i.e. changing the criterion to `~` and searching for a `7` on its own in the tenth field. This matches `7NULNULNUL...` in the tenth field. However, using:

```
$10 ~ "^7\0+$"
```

i.e. matching against `7` followed by one or more explicitly specified `NUL` characters (octal zero) fails to match.

If this is expected behaviour, can someone explain it to me? Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve in gawk?

Comment: That sounds like awk *is* recognizing the `NUL`s as not digit characters. So it sounds like what you want is for awk to *ignore* `NUL`s as characters and treat them like a separator (or just ignore them entirely)? So use `gsub` to strip them?

Comment: No, it would appear that gawk is recognising the `NUL`s as digits (or ignoring them completely), hence `[[:digit:]]+` is matching `7NULNULNUL...` which is unexpected behaviour from everything I've read. I would prefer a pure gawk solution if at all possible, and I don't want to strip the `NUL`s as I want to recognise and log them as invalid.

Comment: Since I'm using `!~` the above code should, I believe, print a record for which the 10th field is `7NULNUL...` as that should NOT match `^[[:digit:]]+$`

Comment: Indeed. I misread the inversion there and was mislead by my testing. I can confirm that gawk 4.1.1 seems to behave as you indicated. I don't see that behavior with gawk 3.1.5 on another machine though.

Comment: I thought, for a minute, that perhaps it was incorrectly terminating the field on the `NUL` but some quick testing indicates that it isn't going that. So now I wonder if this is a lower-level issue in how the regex function operates and how it handles embedded `NUL` characters.

Comment: Thanks, I may be able to revert to an earlier version of gawk... though some consistency would be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74049/discussion-between-matt-wenham-and-etan-reisner).